# Objeto dinámico para un SGBD

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, hashmap

¡Qué tal!
Tengo una duda de cómo crear un objeto que sea dinámico a partir de los datos que introduzca el usuario dada una consulta como en MySQL.

Supongamos que un usuario mete la siguiente query:

```
> CREATE TABLE NOMBRE(nombre varchar(20), edad int,precio float);
```

A partir de éste, deseo costruir la clase de la siguiente manera:

```
/*Código en JAVA*/
public class NOMBRE{
     String nombre;
     int nombre;
     float precio;
  }
```

Ya he recuperado los tipos de datos y nombres, propios de Java.
Ahora me gustaría formar esta clase, o cualquier otra dada por la consulta, de manera dinámica.

```
public ArrayList<String> getDataTable(String SQL_QUERY) {
    List<String> data;          /*Lista de datos a mandar*/
    String[] segment;           /*Segmentos de la consulta*/
    String sentence = "", flag = "";    /*sentencia de query y bandera para formato*/

    /*QUITA LA SENTENCIA GENERADORA DE TABLA: 'CREATE TABLE'*/
    if (SQL_QUERY.contains(CREATE_TB[0])) {
        segment = SQL_QUERY.split(CREATE_TB[0]);
        sentence = segment[1];
    } else if (SQL_QUERY.contains(CREATE_TB[1])) {
        segment = SQL_QUERY.split(CREATE_TB[1]);
        sentence = segment[1];
    } else {
        System.out.println("Syntaxis error");
        sentence = null;
    }
    /*-----------------------------------------------------*/

    if (sentence != null) {
        flag = getNameTable(SQL_QUERY) + "(";
        try {
            sentence = sentence.replace(flag, "");   /*Obtiene los datos de la tabla*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getCause());
        }

        segment = null;
        flag = "";
        segment = sentence.split("(\\)|\\(|;)");    /*Separa los datos de la tabla si encuentra: ';' , ')' , ')', ','
                                                    y los asigna al segmento reservado*/
        sentence = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < segment.length; i++) {
            if (!isNumeric(segment[i])) {
                sentence = sentence + segment[i];       /*Quita/Omite el formato de varchar(num)*/
            }
        }
        segment = null;
        segment = sentence.split(",");

        data = Arrays.asList(segment);  /*Asigna los elementos del segmento a la lista*/

        /*--CASTEO DE UN OBJETO LIST A UN ARRAYLIST--*/
        ArrayList<String> listOfData = new ArrayList<>(data.size());
        listOfData.addAll(data);
        /*-------------------------------------------*/

        listOfData.add(0, getNameTable(SQL_QUERY));        /*Siempre el primer elemento será el nombre de la tabla*/            
        listOfData = convertData(listOfData);            /*Convierte los tipos de datos para ser interpretados por JAVA*/
        listOfData = correctFormat(listOfData);            /*Establece el formato typo_de_dato,nombre_de_dato y se guardan*/

        return listOfData;
    }else{
        System.err.println("Syntaxis Error");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Mientras que los metodos *convertData(ArrayList)* y *correctFormat(ArrayList)* son los siguientes, respectivamente:

*Método convertData(ArrayList)*

```
private static ArrayList<String> convertData(ArrayList<String> listOfData) {
    String flag = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < listOfData.size(); i++) {
        if (listOfData.get(i).contains("varchar")) {                /*Verifica VARCHAR/varchar*/
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("varchar", "String");  
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("VARCHAR")) {
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("VARCHAR", "String");
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("FLOAT")) {           /*Verifica FLOAT/float*/
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("FLOAT", "float");
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("float")) {
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("float", "float");
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("INT")) {             /*Verifica INT/int*/
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("INT", "int");
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("int")) {
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("int", "int");
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("SHORT")) {            /*Verifica SHORT/short*/
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("SHORT", "short");
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("short")) {
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("short", "short");
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("LONG")) {             /*Verifica LONG/long*/
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("LONG", "long");
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("long")) {            
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("long", "long");
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("DOUBLE")) {          /*Verifica DOUBLE/double*/
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("DOUBLE", "double");
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("double")) {
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("double", "double");
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("BOOL")) {            /*Verifica BOOL/bool*/
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("BOOL", "boolean");
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("bool")) {
            flag = listOfData.get(i).replace("bool", "boolean");
        }
        listOfData.set(i, flag);
        flag = "";
    }
    return listOfData;
}
```

*Método convertData(ArrayList)*

```
private static ArrayList<String> correctFormat(ArrayList<String> listOfData) {
    String TypeDataPrim = "";
    String NameDataPrim = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < listOfData.size(); i++) {
        int ln = listOfData.get(i).length();
        if (listOfData.get(i).contains("String")) {
            TypeDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(ln - LENGTH_STRING);
            NameDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(0, ln - LENGTH_STRING);
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("int")) {
            TypeDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(ln - LENGTH_INT);
            NameDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(0, ln - LENGTH_INT);
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("short")) {
            TypeDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(ln - LENGTH_SHORT);
            NameDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(0, ln - LENGTH_SHORT);
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("boolean")) {
            TypeDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(ln - LENGTH_BOOLEAN);
            NameDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(0, ln - LENGTH_BOOLEAN);
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("double")) {
            TypeDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(ln - LENGTH_DOUBLE);
            NameDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(0, ln - LENGTH_DOUBLE);
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("long")) {
            TypeDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(ln - LENGTH_LONG);
            NameDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(0, ln - LENGTH_LONG);
        } else if (listOfData.get(i).contains("float")) {
            TypeDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(ln - LENGTH_FLOAT);
            NameDataPrim = listOfData.get(i).substring(0, ln - LENGTH_FLOAT);
        }
        listOfData.set(i, TypeDataPrim + " " + NameDataPrim + ";");
        TypeDataPrim = "";
        NameDataPrim = "";
    }
    return listOfData;
}
```

Aquí un ejemplo de lo que hacen dichos métodos. El primer elemento del ArrayList es el nombre de la tabla/clase siempre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los nombres de los atributos y el tipo de dato son ingresados de manera separada?, o el usuario simplemente pega todo el query y listo?, es decir, le pides al usuario: ingrese atributo #1, luego atributo #2, ahora ingrese el tipo de dato del #1, etc... ? Si pones el código que llevas hasta ahora podríamos ver mejor tu situación.

Comment: @RobertGomez Ingresas todo el query de manera como se suele ingresar en MySQL.

Comment: No has dado muchos detalles todavía. Si el usuario ingresa el query en el mismo MySQL entonces, desde Java puedes crear consultas que te devuelven el nombre de atributo y si tipo (con ayuda de Google), con esto podrás crear tu clase a partir de esas informaciones. Si ofreces más detalles sobre el flujo de tu programa, fuera mejor. Dónde pides el query?, App para teléfono, App desktop, qué IDE usas, versión de Java, pides el query en un TextField (si usas Java Swing), son muchas preguntas y con ambigüedad no puedo ayudarte.

Comment: @RobertGomez ya he subido el código que realiza estas consultas.
La entrada es por consola en NetBeans 8.2 con Java 8.0.